# Dynamically create html checkbox ID asp.net forms

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to create some HTML checkboxes in my program.aspx file so then I can use javascript to postback to my codebehind, the page renders fine however when I view source all checkboxes have `id='0'`
Does anyone know how to assign an ID dynamically?

I've also tried `id=<%= a.ID.tostring() % />` as it's an int. I've also played around with various combinations of single quotes and double quotes around `<%= a.ID %>`

```
 <% foreach (var a in records) { %>
      <tr>
           <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<%= a.ID %>" />     
           </li>
      </tr>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working on another page, I'll figure out the answer and post here afterwards